# Can someone explain what exactly this error means,TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

Tags: python

I have zero idea as to why I'm getting this error.

Comment: The error seems to be pretty clear. Perhaps you should post code that you think should work but does not.

Comment: Also, there are very, very few reasons to use `issubclass`.

Comment: Maybe you were meaning to use `isinstance()` instead?

Comment: I'm not using issubclass.I'm trying to establish a relationship between two objects.Class X has an attribute which should be of type class Y.I will post both class files ka code,but they are quite big and I'm a newbie in python and on stack overflow too...so if there is a particular way to do it,please enlighten me

Comment: @gizgok: As a start, post the code where this error is thrown.

Comment: I'm using ZODB3 as backend.The error is given in serialize.py which is zodb3 file.
 
if issubclass(klass, Broken):
            # We got a broken class. We might need to make it
            # PersistentBroken
            if not issubclass(klass, broken.PersistentBroken):
                klass = broken.persistentBroken(klass)
Pardon me for not knowing how to post codes and can someone please tell me how to do it

Comment: @gizgok: Just post you code, highlight it and click the little buttons with the 1s and 0s. This will indent the text by four spaces and thus formatting it as code.

Comment: For those using Pydantic or FastAPI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75295652/9439097

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that you don't provide a class as argument for `issubclass()`. Both arguments have to be classes. Second argument can also be a tuple of classes.

**If you show the code that throws this error, we can help further.**

---

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html):

> **issubclass(class, classinfo)**
>   Return `true` if `class` is a subclass (direct or indirect) of `classinfo`. A class is considered a subclass of itself. `classinfo` may be a tuple of class objects, in which case every entry in `classinfo` will be checked. In any other case, a `TypeError` exception is raised.

Comment: @Felix:
I have club class and manager class.Club class has attribute Manager where a instance of manager class should be saved.I have written functions for relationships vice-versa.I think this functions are resulting in giving issubclass error

Comment: It would have made more sense to let non classes return False in my opinion, but alas this is what we got.

Answer (score 28):

The 2 arguments of `issubclass()` should be classes, not instances of an object.

consider this sample:

```
>>> issubclass( 1, int )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
>>> issubclass( type(1), int )
True    
>>> isinstance( 1, int )
True
```

the key is the use of the `type()` function to get the type of an instance for use with the `issubclass()` function, which, as noted in another comment, is equivalent to calling `isinstance()`

Comment: well, you are right... i don't want to confuse an obvious beginner in python. i should have used 'instances of an object' (correct me if i am wrong)

Answer (score 15):

For those using **Pydantic** or **FastAPI** and having problems with this error.
Here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70384637/7335848

Comment: For me (also Pydantic user) this helped:
```pip install --force-reinstall typing-extensions==4.5.0```

Comment: For me this was caused due to mismatch of pydantic and typing-exxtensions versions. Installing with `mamba` does not always follow the version specs strictly.

Comment: is also fixed in later python versions, so you could pin based on the python being used.  (If you're writing a library and that information isn't knowable in advance)

Answer (score 5):

As @Domi W suggested in one of the comments, this is what worked for me and solved my issues with `feast` complaining about `TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class`:

```
pip install --force-reinstall typing-extensions==4.5.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue as well and on the end I've just updated spacy in the requirements from **spacy==3.2.4** to **spacy==3.2.6**

Answer (score 1):

When you use "=" instead of ":" declaring an attibute of class, you get the error:
**TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class**. The number 1 say you that you have the error in the first argument

*this is incorrect:*

```
class AnyClass(BaseClass):
    email = str
```

*this is correct:*

```
class AnyClass(BaseClass):
    email : str
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this method tells you if the first parameter is a subclass of the second. So naturally, both your parameters need to be classes. It appears from your call, that you have called `issubclass` without any parameters, which confuses the interpreter.

Calling `issubclass` is like asking the interpreter: "Hey! is this class a subclass of this other class?". However, since you have not provided two classes, you have essentially asked the interpretter: "Hey! I'm not going to show you anything, but tell me if this it's a subclass". This confuses the interpreter and that's why you get this error.

Answer (score -2):

The first argument to `issubclass()` needs to be of type "class".

http://pyref.infogami.com/issubclass