# fastAPI multiple model file relationship causes circular dependency issue

Tags: python, fastapi, circular-dependency

I am relatively new to fastAPI.

I am developing a set of APIs. To make my project better structured, I separated my model into multiple files. For now, I have an Employee and Skills table. There is a one to many relationship from employee to skills, where each employee can have multiple skills which are tied together with `employee_id`.

This is my main class, that I have used routers:

```
    #main.py
    app.include_router(skill.router, prefix="/skill", tags=["skill"])
    app.include_router(employee.router, prefix="/employee", tags=["employee"])


    #employee.py
    Base = declarative_base()
    class Employee(Base):
        __tablename__ = "core_employees"
        employee_id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
        first_name = mapped_column(String)
        last_name = mapped_column(String)
        skills = relationship(Skill)

    #skill.py
    Base = declarative_base()
    class Skill(Base):
        __tablename__ = "skills"
        skill_id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
        employee_id = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey(Employee.employee_id))
        skill_name = mapped_column(String)
        skill_level = mapped_column(Integer)
        employee = relationship(Employee)
```

The file structure is like this:

```
    main.py
    model/
    │
    ├── employee.py
    ├── skill.py
```

I initially had difficulty with separating models into different files, as for instance       `employee = relationship('Employee')` was not working, and I had to pass the actual class.

Now there is a problem. `skill.py` has to import `employee.py` and vice versa, which is a circular dependency problem.

I tried to add both imports to a [package](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/1873) (make models a package) but it did not work for me. I also tried [forward refs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63420889/fastapi-pydantic-circular-references-in-separate-files) which also did not work. Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one common `Base` for all related models.

```
    #main.py
    app.include_router(skill.router, prefix="/skill", tags=["skill"])
    app.include_router(employee.router, prefix="/employee", tags=["employee"])


    #database.py
    Base = declarative_base()


    #employee.py
    from database import Base
    class Employee(Base):
        __tablename__ = "core_employees"
        employee_id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
        first_name = mapped_column(String)
        last_name = mapped_column(String)
        skills = relationship("Skill" )

    #skill.py
    from database import Base
    from employee import Employee
    class Skill(Base):
        __tablename__ = "skills"
        skill_id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
        employee_id = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey(Employee.employee_id))
        skill_name = mapped_column(String)
        skill_level = mapped_column(Integer)
        employee = relationship(Employee)
```