# How to debug Fastapi openapi generation error

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi, openapi-generator

I spend some time going over this error but had no success.

> File "C:\Users\ebara.conda\envs\asci\lib\site-packages\fastapi\openapi\utils.py", line 388, in get_openapi
> flat_models=flat_models, model_name_map=model_name_map

> File "C:\Users\ebara.conda\envs\asci\lib\site-packages\fastapi\utils.py", line 28, in get_model_definitions
> model_name = model_name_map[model]

> KeyError: <class 'pydantic.main.Body_login_access_token_api_v1_login_access_token_post'>

The problem is that I'm trying to build a project with user authentication from OpenAPI form to create new users in database.

I've used backend part of this template project https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql

Everything works except for Authentication like [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/blob/490c554e23343eec0736b06e59b2108fdd057fdc/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/backend/app/app/api/api_v1/endpoints/login.py#L22).

```
@router.post("/login/access-token", response_model=schemas.Token)
def login_access_token(
    db: Session = Depends(deps.get_db), form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()) -> Any:
```

When I add this part `form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()` - and go to /docs page - this error appears (Failed to load API definition. Fetch error. Internal Server Error /openapi.json)

[image: error picture] .

The server itself runs in normal mode, but it can't load the open API. If I remove the aforementioned formdata part - then everything works smoothly, but without Authorisation. I tried to debug it, but I have no success. I think it might be connected to a dependency graph or some start-up issues, but have no guess how to trace it back.

Here is the full working example which will reproduce the error. The link points out the code which causes the problem. If you will comment out lines 18-39 - the docs will open without any problems.
https://github.com/BEEugene/fastapi_error_demo/blob/master/fastapi_service/api/api_v1/endpoints/login.py

Any ideas on how to debug or why this error happens?

Comment: How are you running the app?

Comment: @niko, I run it with this command `uvicorn app.main:app --reload --log-level debug --port 6008`

Comment: Have you tried running it via docker? I.e. `docker-compose up --build -d` (This is the intended usage afaik) If so, does the error persist?

Comment: @Chris, thank you for the comment. I added the link to the GitHub repository. This can be reproduced within a service, so I added the full version to test it.

Comment: @tiangolo, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in my case - the main error issue was that I was an idiot.

As said, if you will [comment out](https://github.com/BEEugene/fastapi_error_demo/blob/master/fastapi_service/api/api_v1/endpoints/login.py) lines 18-39 - the docs will open without any problems. But, you will notice this warning:

> UserWarning: Duplicate Operation ID read_users_api_v1_users__get for
> function read_users at
> ...\fastapi_error\fastapi_service\api\api_v1\endpoints\users.py
> warnings. Warn(message)

I've started to compare all the files and it is appeared that I included router to the fastapi twice:

```
import logging
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

from fastapi_service.api.api_v1.api import api_router
from fastapi_service.core.config import settings
from fastapi_service.core.event_handlers import (start_app_handler,
                                                 stop_app_handler)

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def get_app(mode="prod") -> FastAPI:

    fast_app = FastAPI(title=settings.PROJECT_NAME,
                       version=settings.APP_VERSION,
                       debug=settings.IS_DEBUG)
                       # openapi_url=f"{settings.API_V1_STR}/openapi.json")
    #  first time when I included the router
    fast_app.include_router(api_router, prefix=f"{settings.API_V1_STR}")
    fast_app.mode = mode
    logger = log.getChild("get_app")
    logger.info("adding startup")
    fast_app.add_event_handler("startup", start_app_handler(fast_app))
    logger.info("adding shutdown")
    fast_app.add_event_handler("shutdown", stop_app_handler(fast_app))

    return fast_app


app = get_app()

# Set all CORS enabled origins
if settings.BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS:
    app.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=[str(origin) for origin in settings.BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS],
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=["*"],
        allow_headers=["*"],
    )
#  second time when I included the router
app.include_router(api_router, prefix=settings.API_V1_STR)
```

So, if you comment out (or just delete) the second router introduction - the app will work normally.

It seems, that the answer to my question on how to debug this error - is to find the point where the bug appears in fastapi and compare the values in it to the version where there is no error. In my case the number of keys in different dictionaries differed in the function get_model_definitions.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Depends function without an argument. Maybe in the console, you were having the error provoked by a function. You must pass the *OAuth2PasswordRequestForm* function after importing it from **fastapi.security** to get the result you were expecting.

`from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordRequestForm`

`form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(OAuth2PasswordRequestForm)`

it might work.

Comment: Hi! Thank you, unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: @Alexander, Depends can be use both ways,when you use a fastapi class like ```OAuth2PasswordRequestForm``` you can use ``` form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends() ``` it is what is suggest by the doc btw.

Example: https://github.com/Bastien-BO/fastapi-RBAC-microservice/blob/main/app/routers/auth.py

Comment: I will try that mode, if I am not mistaken I got an error when i used that way you suggest. Thanks for the link to read about it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. For me it was because I had code like this

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class A(BaseModel):
   b: B

class B(BaseModel):
   c: int
```

but instead, `Class B` **should have been defined above class A**. This fixed it:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class B(BaseModel):
   c: int

class A(BaseModel):
   b: B
```

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70384637/9439097

### Regaring your original question on how to debug these or similar errors:

You probably have your routes defined somewhere. Comment all of your routers/routes out, then the openapi docs should generate (and they should show you have no routes. Then, enable the routes one by one and see which one causes the error. THis is how I debuged my situation.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had two identical function names with identical parameters, when I renamed one of the functions the documentation gets generated

my error was something like

```py
KeyError: <class 'pydantic.main.Body_post_message_post_QA_chat_post'>
```

and the function name and endpoint that had the error was

**endpoint:** post_QA_chat

**function name:** post message

it seems the class name that was mentioned in error

`Body_post_message_post_QA_chat_post`

named in a way

`Body_function-name_endpoint`

I think this could help to debug